# Does Gyro Ball get affected by Attack decrease?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I want my Contrary Shuckle to have Shell Smash and Gyro Ball, but inverted Shell Smash would give Shuckle -2Atk, -2SpAtk and -2Spd and +1Def and +1Spdef. But will Gyro Ball's damage be lowered by the -2Atk? I've gone on Battle Spot to test this and Gyro Ball did an extremely bad amount of damage. The speed that my Shuckle is at right now is 15 at level 100.

Comment: Curse with Gyro Ball is a better bet.

Comment: @StrixVaria Not with a Contrary Shuckle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it does.
*Gyro ball* inflicts more damage the slower the user is compared to the target, calculated by the following formula:

```
Base Power = 25 × (Target's Current Speed / User's Current Speed)
```

But what you get is only the **Base Power** of the move, not the effective damage you will do. If you have a -2 stage on attack, Gyro Ball will be half its normal power.

Comment: Might be worth adding that you can make Shuckle hold a White Herb to revert the Negative Stats back to 0 after a (single) Shell Smash

Comment: @Robotnik that's true, but there are better items for Shuckle, imho.

Comment: It's also worth noting (in case it wasn't immediately obvious after @pinckerman posted the base power formula) that for Gyro Ball, Shell Smash would not affect the final outcome as the attack boost/drop would negate the speed boost/drop. So if Shuckle didn't have any other attacking moves, negating stats drops with a White Herb makes no sense and is a waste of an item slot.